# How is the timeoutID accessible before initialization?

Tags: javascript

```js
function addNew() {
    let id = setTimeout( function() {console.log(id)}, 0)
}

addNew()
```

How is id able to be accessed before initialization? I think this is no different from the second code snippet.

```
function customTimeout(fn) {
    fn()
    return 32423
}

function addNew() {
    let id = customTimeout( function() {console.log(id)})
}

addNew()
```

Comment: I think the base of the confusion here lies in the nature of `setTimeout` call. It's not blocking, it just is called, it puts its argument to the task queue, and returns the result, the timeout id. Then `addNew` function and the rest of the script continue their execution. After all the scripts are done, the task queue fires the timed function. At that point of time, `id` variable has got its value for a long time ago. JS has only a single thread, and everything is executed on that thread, even asynchronously called timers.

Answer (score 1):

Variables which have not initialized yet cannot be *directly referenced* by a line that runs until the variable gets initialized (the `let id =` line), but it's still permitted for functions which have *not been called yet* to reference the variables inside.

In the first snippet, the `setTimeout` callback does not run until the `let id =` line has finished initializing the `id` variable, so it's permitted.

In the second snippet, the callback passed to `customTimeout` is running *before* the `let id =` line in `addNew` has finished initializing `id`, so it's not permitted.

```js
// Permitted:

const fn = () => {
  // do something with someVariable
  console.log(someVariable);
};
// The above is fine
let someVariable = 'foo';
// just make sure fn is called ONLY AFTER `let someVariable;` runs
fn();
```

```js
// Not permitted:

const fn = () => {
  console.log(someVariable);
};
fn();
let someVariable = 'foo';
```

```js
// Permitted, since fn is called asynchronously:

function customTimeout(fn) {
    Promise.resolve().then(fn);
    return 32423
}

function addNew() {
    let id = customTimeout( function() {console.log(id)})
}

addNew()
```

```js
// Permitted, since fn is called asynchronously:

function customTimeout(fn) {
    setTimeout(fn);
    return 32423
}

function addNew() {
    let id = customTimeout( function() {console.log(id)})
}

addNew()
```

```js
// Permitted, since fn is called after `id` has finished being assigned to:

function customTimeout(fn) {
    return [12345, fn];
}

function addNew() {
    let [id, fn] = customTimeout( function() {console.log(id)})
    fn();
}

addNew()
```

Comment: I still do not understand. When is id initialized? Can the behavior of setTimeout be replicated by a custom written function?

Comment: A variable gets initialized when its line runs, right after anything on the right of a possible `=` runs. `const foo = someExpression` initializes `foo` (allows it to be referenced in a line that runs) once `someExpression` finishes evaluating to a value.

Comment: `setTimeout` is an API provided by the *browser* - it's not something you can implement on your own. But to replicate the issue and see different possibilities, you can just save the callback in a variable, and then call the function either before or after the variable referenced inside the callback is initialized - like in the final snippet.

Comment: I still do not understand could you provide me with a code snippet of a rewrite of my customTimeout function so that it behaves in the same way as setTimeout in my first code snippet?

Comment: I do understand the code snippet in your answer but I don't understand how my first and second code snippets are any different.

Comment: Your second code is running `fn()` in `customTimeout` *before* the right side of `let id = customTimeout(...)` has finished resolving, so the `id` variable has not been properly initialized yet. You need to wait for the right side of the `=` on the line that the variable is initialized on to resolve to a value before the variable in question may be referenced directly.

Comment: I saw the unaccept, is it still not clear?

Answer (score 0):

See example, hope you understand.

```js
function addNew() {
    let id = setTimeout(  // <-- 1
                function() { // <-- 2
                    console.log(id) // <--- here
                            }
                      , 0)
}

addNew()




/*
* It will not work.
*/
function addOld() {
    console.log(id)
    let id = 2;
}
addOld()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setTimeout` (even with a timeout of `0`), the callback doesn't run right away.  It's placed into a stack to be ran at some point in the future.

So, in your 1st example, you are setting `id` to the "timeoutID" returned by `setTimeout`.  When the callback is ran in the *future* (asynchronously), `id` is there and the callback can see it.

In your 2nd example, you are passing a callback to `customTimeout`.  Before this function returns anything, the callback is ran.  It's ran immediately (synchronously) and after the callback is ran, then `customTimeout` returns a value.

Since this value is returned *after* the function is ran, the function cannot see it.